# Como hacer una consulta a la BD de dos tablas que me devuelva los valores de la otra tabla y no el código en Django

Tags: django

Tengo los siguientes modelos:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    titulo=models.CharField(max_length=50,null=False,blank=False)
    descripcion=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=False,blank=False)
    cuerpo=RichTextUploadingField(verbose_name="Contenido")
    img=models.ImageField(upload_to="media")
    tag=models.ManyToManyField(Tag)
    comentario=models.ManyToManyField(Comentario)
    activo=models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Activo")

class Tag(models.Model):
    nombre=models.CharField(max_length=10,null=False,blank=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nombre
```

Para recuperar todos los registros de la DB lo hago así:

```
class PostViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    queryset = Post.objects.all()
```

De esta forma obtengo todos los registros de Post y a su vez el código o Id del modelo tag, mi pregunta es si con las funciones de Django puedo recuperar en ves del Id del tag, recuperar el nombre directamente, o necesariamento necesito escribir de manera directa el sql.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El arreglo tenía que hacerlo en los serializadores. Lo hice de la siguiente manera:

De primer lugar tenia el serializador de Posts asi:

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Post
            fields = "__all__"
```

Tuve que añadir los serializadores para los modelos de las relaciones, para mi caso los siguientes:
class TagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
class Meta:
model = Tag
fields = "**all**"

```
class ComentarioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comentario
        fields = "__all__"
```

Finalmente, en el serializador de Post tenia que agregar estos modelados serializados respectivamente, los atributos que contiene este debe ser el mismo que se estableció en el modelo; es decir, en el modelo de Post tenia el atributo tag=..., para el serializador debe tener el mismo nombre.

```
class PostSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    tag = TagSerializer(many=True)
    comentario = ComentarioSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Post
        fields = "__all__"
```